# How to get current location on google mapview in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

In this my code i did not understand where i did mistake in my code .I did not get current location on map view with pin point image. How to get the Latitude & Latitude and pass in Geo point. then pass the value OverlayItem ..

```
public class HelloGoogleMaps2 extends MapActivity implements LocationListener{

 private LocationManager locationManager;
 private String provider;
 int lat;
 int lng;
 MyLocationOverlay  myLocOverlay;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);    
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    Log.d("provider  ","Provider  "+provider);
    Log.d("provider  ","Provider  "+provider);
    Log.d("provider  ","Provider  "+provider);
    Log.d("location","Location "+location);

    Log.d("location","Location "+location);        

    Log.d("location","Location "+location);
    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
      System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
      onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
      //latituteField.setText("Location not available");
     // longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
    }


    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    myLocOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapOverlays.add(myLocOverlay);
    myLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
   //        mc.setCenter(point);
    //        mapView.invalidate();

    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);

      GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat,lng);
OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!");


itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
}


@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

 protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
      }

      /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
      //
      protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
      }

      //
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
         lat = (int) (location.getLatitude()* 1E6);
         lng = (int) (location.getLongitude()* 1E6);
       // latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
       // longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
      }

      //
      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      //
      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }

      //
      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
```

}

Comment: have u try                                             myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() 
  { public void run() {localLat=myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation().getLatitudeE6()/1E6;                                                                                     
   localLng=myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation().getLongitudeE6()/1E6;}
  });                                                                      it may help u ..

Answer (score 2):

The right code is this  ,but also add uses-permissio ,Internet,ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE .user-library .

```
  public class GoogleMapActivity extends  MapActivity implements LocationListener {
  private final static String TAG = GoogleMapActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private MyItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;

double lat;
double lng;
private String provider;
private LocationManager locationManager;

private MapView mapview;

Drawable drawable;



boolean sat = true;
boolean dra = true;

private MapController controller;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // fetch the map view from the layout
    mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    // make available zoom controls
    mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

    // Use the location manager through GPS

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
        lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());

        Log.i(TAG, "Lattitude:" + lat);
        Log.i(TAG, "Longitude:" + lng);
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Current location:\nLatitude: " + lat + "\n"
                        + "Longitude: " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // create geo point
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));

        // get the MapController object
        controller = mapview.getController();

        // animate to the desired point
        controller.animateTo(point);

        // set the map zoom to 13
        // zoom 1 is top world view
        controller.setZoom(13);

        // invalidate the map in order to show changes
        mapview.invalidate();

        drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");
        itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
        mapview.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
        mapview.invalidate();
    } else {

        System.out.println("Location not avilable");
    }

    // when the current location is found – stop listening for updates
    // (preserves battery)
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

public MapView getMapView() {
    return this.mapview;
}


    }
```

`        //here is another of item overlay

```
    public class MyItemizedOverlay  extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>
     {



   private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();


    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context ctx){ 
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));

    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    public void clear() {
        mOverlays.clear();
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        return true;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [MyLocationOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay).

*An Overlay for drawing the user's current location (and accuracy) on the map, and/or a compass-rose inset. Subclases can override dispatchTap() to handle taps on the current location.

You will want to call enableMyLocation() and/or enableCompass(), probably from your Activity's Activity.onResume() method, to enable the features of this overlay. Remember to call the corresponding disableMyLocation() and/or disableCompass() in your Activity's Activity.onPause() method to turn off updates when in the background.

Optionally, the constructor can also take a MapController and use it to keep the "my location" dot visible by panning the map when it would go offscreen, and a View to View.postInvalidate() when location or orientation is changed.

Runnables can be provided in runOnFirstFix(java.lang.Runnable) to be run as soon as we have a fix. (For example, this could center the map and zoom in to show the location.)*

You can find a good tutorial on MyLocationOverlay [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090425180939/http://blogs.itemis.de/frey/2009/04/04/location-based-services-on-android-part-1/)

Comment: Sir i wnat dynamic latitude and longitude and the pass in GeoPoint